# ZF2 Dependency Injection - Injecting tables into classes

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

**Please note: This was ZF beta 1. I doubt this is the same for current release**

I was just attempting to inject dependencies into some of my classes. I thought I had this down as I was already managing it with quite a few things like injecting `database configurations`, `DB adapters` and `auth adapters` into my `UserMapper` class.

I was trying to do the same with some other classes of mine and couldn't work out at all why it just wasn't working like my `UserMapper` class was. Now I see that the `UserMapper` class is being injected into a controller which has an alias set for it at the top of the config file.

So I guess without having it first injected by using a controller... how am I supposed to be injecting stuff into my Models? I'm using the standard `ZF2 Skeleton by EvanDotPro`

My Models are in:

```
Application\Model\
Application\Model\DbTable
```

My config currently looks something like:

```
<?php
return array(
'bootstrap_class' => 'Application\Bootstrap',
'layout'          => 'layouts/layout.phtml',
'di'              => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(
            'index'             => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'view'              => 'Zend\View\PhpRenderer'
        ),

        'Zend\View\HelperLoader' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'map' => array(
                    'url' => 'Application\View\Helper\Url',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'Zend\View\HelperBroker' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'loader' => 'Zend\View\HelperLoader',
            ),
        ),

        'Application\Controller\IndexController' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'userMapper' => 'Application\Model\UserMapper',
                'flashMessenger' => 'Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger'
            )
        ),

        'Application\Model\UserMapper' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'db' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\PdoMysql',
                'authAdapter' => 'Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable',
                'userTable' => 'Application\Model\DbTable\UserTable'
            )
        ),

        'Application\Model\DbTable\UserTable' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'config' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\PdoMysql',
            )
        ),

            // Auth adapter

        'Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'zendDb' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\PdoMysql',
                'tableName' => 'users',
                'identityColumn' => 'username',
                'credentialColumn' => 'password',
                'credentialTreatment' => 'MD5(CONCAT(?,"OSalTyr$"))'
            )
        ),

        // DB Adapter

        'Zend\Db\Adapter\PdoMysql' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'config' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname' => 'blahblah',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        // View

        'Zend\View\PhpRenderer' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'resolver' => 'Zend\View\TemplatePathStack',
                'options'  => array(
                    'script_paths' => array(
                        'application' => __DIR__ . '/../views',
                    ),
                ),
                'broker' => 'Zend\View\HelperBroker',
            ),
        ),

    ),
),

'routes' => array(
    'default' => array(
        'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
        'options' => array(
            'regex'    => '/(?P<controller>[^/]+)(/(?P<action>[^/]+)?)?',
            'spec'     => '/%controller%/%action%',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'error',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'home' => array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'index',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

Thanks, Dominic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahah... I found out why this wasn't working.

Although the above config is correct and I'm defining what I want injecting into what... I wasn't actually using the injected instance of the object in question.

I thought when using 'new thingy();' that DI would magically pick up that it has dependencies and apply them when needed but this is not the case...

What I infact needed to do... was inject the `thingy` class into my `UserMapper` class like a chain and then use the injected instance instead of creating it a `new` instance of it without stuff injected into it.

Like:

`RegisterController` requires `UserMapper` so inject it in and use that instance
`UserMapper` requires `Thingy` so inject it in and use that instance